# What is the connection between i and the matrix that rotates by a right angle.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

From complex analysis we know that multiplying a complex number by i rotates it by a right angle counter-clockwise.  From linear algebra we know that multiplying a vector by the matrix $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$
does the same.  Is there an equation in mathematics that relates them?

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-y\\x\end{pmatrix}$$$$i\cdot(x+iy)=-y+ix$$See the similarity?

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/complex/complex.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers

Comment: View $V=\mathbb C$ as a vector space over $\mathbb R$. While the mapping $f:V\to V$ defined by $z\mapsto iz$ is **not** a scalar multiplication, it is linear. Its matrix representation with respect to the ordered basis $\{1,i\}$ is $\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$.